# Post request gets cut off

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have a problem with my post request in javascript.

I have the following code for sending the post request

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {   
                //stuff
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "/deleteUser", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("username=" + username);
```

And in my node.js express application i receive it like this

```
    var username = req.body.username;
```

Now this works perfect with normal characters (numbers and letters). But when i tried

```
>df)(*&&^%$
```

as username it gets cut off to

```
    >df)(*
```

I suspect it is because of the &.

My question: How do i prevent it from getting cut off.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the `username` parameter into a URI safe string, using `xhttp.send("username="+encodeURIComponent(username));`